# Showing index as xticks for pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe and am trying to plot it, so that it shows in the x-axis the index data from 8-19.

If I do `df.plot()` no labels are shown at all. If I do `df.plot(use_index=True)`, the behaviour is unchanged. Finally I tried `df.plot(xticks=df.index)` but I'm getting an error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seq'`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
null = np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"today sensor 1": {"08": 22.9, "09": 22.7, "10": 22.8, "11": 23.6, "12": 24.1, "13": 24.9,
                                           "14": 25.0, "15": 25.2, "16": 25.7, "17": 26.1, "18": 26.0, "19": 25.8},
                        "today sensor 2": {"08": 24.5, "09": 24.5, "10": 24.8, "11": 25.3, "12": 26.4, "13": 26.7,
                                           "14": 27.1, "15": 27.6, "16": 28.0, "17": 28.0, "18": 28.2, "19": 28.0},
                        "yesterday sensor 1": {"08": null, "09": null, "10": null, "11": null, "12": null, "13": null,
                                               "14": null, "15": null, "16": 23.0, "17": 23.6, "18": 23.5, "19": 23.5},
                        "yesterday sensor 2": {"08": null, "09": null, "10": null, "11": null, "12": null, "13": null,
                                               "14": null, "15": null, "16": 24.8, "17": 24.9, "18": 24.9, "19": 24.8}})

# df.plot(use_index=True)  # does not work
df.plot(xticks=df.index)

plt.show()
```

What is even more strange is that when I do this:

```
ax = df.plot(use_index=True, style=['bs-', 'go-', 'b:', 'g:'])
ax.set_xticklabels(df.index)
plt.show()
```

The xticks will show but they are wrong. Only numbers from 9-14 are snown and every other number only. I would expect 08-19 as xticks.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Is it necessary to have strings as indices?

Comment: The indices are hours. The chart is a temperature chart. I don’t care about the Datatype

Comment: If you don't care use integers (or datetime) and you'll have xticks in your plot.

Comment: This appears to be tracked as a bug here https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19965

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to have string as xticks one possible solution is:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.rename(columns={"index":"hour"})
ax = df.plot(xticks=df.index)
ax.set_xticklabels(df["hour"]);
```

Comment: It works, but it's clearly unexpected and odd behaviour from pandas

Comment: I do agree with you. And I hope someone it's going to figure it out and explain to us.

Comment: This wouldn't work if the index values are not evenly spaced...

Answer (score 10):

Until the bug in Pandas gets fixed, add this after df.plot(), no need for anything else:

```
plt.xticks(range(len(df.index)), df.index)
```

Comment: What if I would set as tick only a subset of that index, like every 10 observation?

Answer (score 1):

Pandas version 0.24 for Python 3.6 (Windows) fixed this problem for me.

Comment: Half-fixed for me but +1. It still displays only every second tick and label.