# How to display x-axis labels for graph of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, linegraph

This code should give the x-axis labels, however it doesn't.

I'm running the code in jupyter with the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Precision': [0.0983, 0.2936, 0.3992, 0.4016, 0.1360],
'Recall': [0.8495, 0.3312, 0.3065, 0.0995, 0.1071],
'F1': [0.1763, 0.3113, 0.3467, 0.1595, 0.1198]
}, index=['EDbase', 'ED + i1', 'ED +i2', 'ED +i3', 'ED +i4'])
lines = df.plot.line()
```

Why doesn't it display the x-axis labels and how do I remedy this issue?

**Image**
[image: plt]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xticks by pandas plot, rename with the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26358200/xticks-by-pandas-plot-rename-with-the-string)

Comment: Another one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50805666/showing-index-as-xticks-for-pandas-plot)

Comment: Wow I'm sorry about that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go champ -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Precision': [0.0983, 0.2936, 0.3992, 0.4016, 0.1360],
'Recall': [0.8495, 0.3312, 0.3065, 0.0995, 0.1071],
'F1': [0.1763, 0.3113, 0.3467, 0.1595, 0.1198]
}, index=['EDbase', 'ED + i1', 'ED +i2', 'ED +i3', 'ED +i4'])
lines = df.plot.line()

# Something to remember
plt.xticks(np.arange(5), df.index)
plt.show()
```

[image: plt]

Comment: For me you are the champ. Thanks!